# How to list items inline in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to list products by Images using PyQT5 (something like online stores), So I want to list them line by line, The problem now is that every item in the List Widget occupy the whole row (I have attached screenshot), Here is the code

[image]

```
class MyListWidget(QListWidget):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
       self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
       self.setSpacing(5)

class TabClass(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       self.vbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()

       self.list_widget = MyListWidget()

       for i in range(10):
           item = QListWidgetItem()
           item.setText(f'item {i}')
           icon = QtGui.QIcon()
           icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/Mohammad Samir/Desktop/p1419921.jpg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
           item.setIcon(icon)
           self.list_widget.addItem(item)


       self.vbox_layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)

       self.setLayout(self.vbox_layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        self.setSpacing(5)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

class TabClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list_widget = MyListWidget()
       
        for i in range(10):
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText(f'item {i}')
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena.jpg"),  
                           QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            item.setIcon(icon)
            self.list_widget.addItem(item)

        self.vbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox_layout)
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TabClass()
    w.resize(680, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Yes It worked ! Thank you so much for your help, I wonder if there is a source where I can find out these methods and read about it, because PyQt5 documentation is one of the most ridiculous things I have ever seen !

Comment: @MohamedSamir  At the documentation you can find all what you need. Check it again. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget-members.html

Comment: They are using C++ code, I mean the documentation for python version is very limited.